# Store firebase object with user id and something a post_id

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic-Angular Project. I'm trying to develop something like a feed where you can post updates (like in Facebook).

I use a Firebase backend and I want to store the users post in this structure: `Posts/uid/post_id/[POST DATAS]`,
but I don't know how to do something like auto_increment in mysql for the post_id.

```
createPost() {
    this.post.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.post.created_at = Date.now();
    this.post.comments = null;
    this.post.dislikes = 0;
    this.post.likes = 0;


    this.afDatabase.object(`post/${this.post.uid}/${--HERE I WANT TO SET THE POST ID--}`).set(this.post);
    this.postSuccessfulAlert();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @mo.becker, I am a little unclear on what exactly it is you're wanting to accomplish. Could you provide some more clarification on your goals/requirement? Are you just wanting to increment an `id` for every post, are you trying to create a unique id for every post, are you trying to auto increment in Firebase or on the frontend? Additional clarification would be helpful.

Comment: right I want an unique id for every  post

Comment: Who is responsible for generating that uid, Angular or Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> but I don't know how to do something like auto_increment in mysql for the post_id.
> ```

Firebase/Firestore does not have an auto increment feature, as far as I know. If you are creating a new document, firebase will automatically assign a new unique id for that document unless you specify the id to use.

If you want the generated document id ahead of time (because you are using the `set` method) then you can assign a docRef and grab the id.

example:

```
const newDoc   = firestoreInstance.collection(`post/${this.post.uid}/posts).doc();
const newDocId = newDoc.id;
```

Firebase uses a `Firebase Timestamp` for its dates whereas you are setting a js date to `this.post.created_at` You should instead use a Firebase Timestamp:

```
const serverTimestamp = firestoreAdmin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
```